# Stores the scroll offset on the page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to maintain my page scroll offset with javascript with the code below:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  var scrollpos = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
  if (scrollpos) {
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('scrollpos');
  }
});

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
});
```

And I've tried it but it's not working, what's wrong with it?

Comment: My first guess would be that since you are using sessionStorage, and not for example localstorage, the data is being cleared when you close the window. "A page session lasts as long as the tab or the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores." Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @HermanNeple Yes, but when using localStorage it will save it even after the browser is closed

Comment: Yes, that's true. With what you want to do, it would probably be easiest to use localStorage, and then also store the date and time the window was closed, so that when the page is loaded again, you can check if it's been under x time. I'm not sure there are any other storage opportunities that really fits your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Using sessionStorage, your scroll-position value is deleted as soon as the tab is closed, so saving sessionStorage before unloading a page would do nothing.

An alternative is to use localStorage. This value wouldn't expire, but if you want the scroll-position only to be saved for some time, you could also store the time and date of the unload. This could be done like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
    const now = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('lastunload', now);
});
```

And then when loading the page you would do:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
    const now = new Date();
    const then = localStorage.getItem('lastunload');
    var diff = Math.abs(now-then)*1000; //this gets the diff in seconds
    if (scrollpos && diff<(10*60)) { //checks if it's been 10 minutes
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
        localStorage.removeItem('scrollpos');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)